# Display Accordion on CLick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

When I click on the 3 line icon I currently just have a simple link back to the homepage of the website. I want to be able to click on it for it then to display a drop down menu so that I can choose a range of different page links for the site. This is to work on Mobile.

```
<div class="icon">
    <ul><a href="home.html"></ul>
    <img src="img/icons/menu-media.png"/></a>
</div>
```

So At the moment the icon links you to a page and nothing else but I am looking for a drop down menu. I have not used bootstrap, just html, css and basic jQuery.

Comment: could you provide more context and some or your code? Also are you using a framework like bootstrap?

Comment: You need to show the code you're having a problem with and maybe someone will help. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I will update now

Comment: Updated, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: If it helps my webiste is [www.gavwellis.com] inspect it to mobile size and you will see

Comment: I visited your website (www.gavwellis.com) and inspect it to mobile mode, but there is no "3 lines icon".

Answer (score 1):

One method:

- First you need to add the collection of links for the different pages, probably in a NAV > UL.
- Style it to be hidden.
- Add a css class that makes the NAV visible when applied to it.
- Put a javascript callback on the hamburger button (three lines) which toggles (adds/removes) the class to the NAV.